# Excess pixel in gradient text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, gradient, fill

I'm practicing adobe illustrator. I wonder how there is an excess pixel in my text when I use gradient. Are there any settings to make it smooth without excess pixel outside/inside the text?

[image: sample text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the text characters to have a fill of `None`... then apply the gradient as an *additional fill* via the appearance panel.

The underlying black edge is due to the characters having a black fill (and anti-aliasing).